# TYPO3 realURL rewrite News Tag Search

Tags: url-rewriting, tags, typo3, realurl, tx-news

I'm using `TYPO3 7.6.x` with `realURL 2.0.14` ans `news 4.2.1`.

I've made a SearchForm-Module, where I can search for Newstags.

Here's my HTML-Output, I'm just looking (TS) for `tx_news_domain_model_tag.title` at my `pidInList=20` and it works:

```
<form method="get" action="/index.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
  <select class="tagSearch" name="tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]">
    <option value="" selected="">Tags</option>
    <option value="12">Tag A</option>
    <option value="8">Tag >B</option>
    ...
  </select>
</form>
```

At the moment my Links are like:
`http://www.example.com/index.php?id=14&tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Btags%5D=15`

If I click on a news tag below my news record, I'll get:

```
domain.com/articles/tagname/
```

How can I tell realURL, to rewrite `tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]` from my selectbox? At the moment I use the realURL-Configuration from `Ext.news` ([advanced setup](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html))

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this has nothing to do how the RealUrl works, since it is the default browser behaviour of submitting a form, which generates the non-user friendly URL.

The easiest way to fix it would be to rewrite the form into a list with `<a href="">` links. These links will get processed automatically with RealUrl.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I try to change my select/option-list to a ul/li/a href list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an ul/li you could also generate the url in the value attribute of the option and after form submit, redirect via JS to the selected URL